# System.drawing.common the type initializer for 'gdip' threw an exception

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core, worksheet, closedxml

This is my code to add a picture to a worksheet. I get the picture as a byte from the database. .Net Core framework version is 2.2.104. This is an API project. In my locale, the code works well. I use the ClosedXML component 0.95.4 version as below.

```
[HttpPost("GetTowel")]
public IActionResult GetTowel()
{
    string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    string fileName = "Towel Quotation.xlsx";
    try
    {
        using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Towel Quotation");
            
            byte[] bytes = _fileService.Get(159).FileInBytes;
            System.IO.Stream x = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);

            //the exception is throwed at this line:
            **var image = worksheet.AddPicture(x).MoveTo(worksheet.Cell("P1")).Scale(1.0);**

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                var content = stream.ToArray();
                return File(content, contentType, fileName);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ErrorResultFormatter.PrepareErrorResult("",ex.Message));
    }
}
```

[image: frameworks]

My Kubernetes server information is below:

```
System.drawing.common the type initializer for 'gdip' threw an exception
```

```
*FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj Nuget.Config ./ RUN dotnet restore /property:Configuration=Release
--configfile=Nuget.Config --no-cache --force
COPY . ./temp/ WORKDIR /app/temp RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+" ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="*****" WORKDIR /app COPY --from=build /app/temp/out ./ ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "blahblah.dll"]*
```

On the server-side, I get the exception as below: "system.drawing.common the type initializer for 'gdip' threw an exception"

I have searched many times on google. That way is suggested generally to add docker file:

```
RUN apt-get install libgdiplus
```

But this way also didn't solve my problem. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a windows or a linux container?

Comment: You may use this repo for generating simple excel files: https://github.com/doxa-labs/ExcelLabs

Comment: You need libc6-dev too. Check that it is installed.

Answer (score 39):

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev
        
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
        
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ...
    
.
.
.
    
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "...dll"]
```

I am running `apt-get update and install` command on the second line. You may run your command like this. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: The `apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev` bits did the trick; thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Fix for ClosedXML 0.96.0, .NET 6, and Alpine Linux throwing the following exception when creating an Excel file:

> The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception

1. Add the `libgdiplus` package

   Dockerfile

   ```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine 
    RUN apk add libgdiplus --repository http://dl-.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ 
    RUN apk add ttf-freefont libssl1.1 
    ...
   ```
2. Enable `System.Drawing` support for non-Windows platforms: ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action)):

   In your project file (`*.csproj`), add:

   ```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport" Value="true" />
    </ItemGroup
   ```

Answer (score 19):

The most accepted answer did not work for me on ubuntu 20.04 and it looks like support for non-windows os's is removed for .NET 6:

[System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only)

The suggested alternatives are:

> To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the
> following libraries:
>
> ImageSharp https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

> SkiaSharp https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp

> Microsoft.Maui.Graphics https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics

Comment: From .NET 6 this is the best answer because it includes also a specific Microsoft workaround to keep working `System.Drawing.Common` also with .NET 6 even if it is not advisable.

Comment: There are at least two forks that aim to add some kind of linux support [imagesharp based](https://github.com/0xced/ClosedXML/tree/ImageSharp) and [skiasharp based](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentPartner.ClosedXML/)

Comment: this does not help if the error come from closed-xml

Answer (score 9):

For me, the following fixed the issue (in local tests and also deployments using Ubuntu Agent in Azure):

Here is what I have in my Dockerfile:

```
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as base
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus
  WORKDIR /app
  EXPOSE 80
```

Here is what I have added into every *.csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport" Value="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And I also had to install this NuGet package too: "*System.Drawing.Common*"

Comment: This worked for me.  I did not have to add `System.Drawing.Common` though.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I don't even have to install the NuGet package.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when deploying on Linux server

try it :

```
sudo apt-get install -y libgdiplus
```

and restart server

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: I met this problem on macos, so solution is ```sudo port install libgdiplus``` or ```brew install mono-libgdiplus```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the libgdi NuGet package within your project. See: https://github.com/eugeneereno/libgdiplus-packaging

`dotnet add package ereno.linux-x64.eugeneereno.System.Drawing`

For Mac users see: https://github.com/eugeneereno/libgdiplus-packaging

Answer (score 0):

Add in that code in your docker file for install the libgdi.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus
```

After that add in that code in your .csproj file for enable unix support.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And be victorious mate!